o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed Error 18237
Hello all I am having an issue with viewing my app on localhost: 8080 and I keep getting the above error, 1.  I am wondering if this is why I cant view the app.  2. How do I fix it? below is  my log
2024-07-23T23:32:38.909-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication : Starting SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication using Java 22.0.2 with PID 18237 (/Users/dereksands/IdeaProjects/Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy/target/classes started by dereksands in /Users/dereksands/IdeaProjects/Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy)
2024-07-23T23:32:38.911-04:00 DEBUG 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication : Running with Spring Boot v3.3.1, Spring v6.1.10
2024-07-23T23:32:38.912-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-23T23:32:38.961-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-07-23T23:32:38.961-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-07-23T23:32:39.774-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-23T23:32:39.830-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 49 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-07-23T23:32:40.484-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-07-23T23:32:40.500-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-23T23:32:40.500-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]
2024-07-23T23:32:40.551-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/MavDesk]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-23T23:32:40.551-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1589 ms
2024-07-23T23:32:40.717-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-23T23:32:40.771-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-07-23T23:32:40.802-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-23T23:32:41.110-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-23T23:32:41.140-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-23T23:32:41.578-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2d62c770
2024-07-23T23:32:41.580-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-23T23:32:41.618-04:00  WARN 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQL8Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-07-23T23:32:41.619-04:00  WARN 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2024-07-23T23:32:42.589-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-23T23:32:42.754-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-23T23:32:43.100-04:00  WARN 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-07-23T23:32:43.300-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] r$InitializeUserDetailsManagerConfigurer : Global AuthenticationManager configured with UserDetailsService bean with name userDetailsService
2024-07-23T23:32:43.373-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2024-07-23T23:32:43.421-04:00  WARN 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
2024-07-23T23:32:43.422-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-23T23:32:43.424-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-07-23T23:32:43.430-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-07-23T23:32:43.433-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-07-23T23:32:43.447-04:00  INFO 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-23T23:32:43.467-04:00 ERROR 18237 --- [Sands_Derek_MavDesk_CaseStudy] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication.main(SandsDerekMavDeskCaseStudyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity@30cfe4ef of type class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:71) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospectorRequestTransformer': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:203) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1194) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:486) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$1.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:438) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.setApplicationContext(WebSecurity.java:397) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:110) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1780) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.initializeBeanIfNeeded(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:98) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:67) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'authController' method 
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission()
to {POST [/auth]}: There is already 'authController' bean method
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission(String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'authController' method 
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission()
to {POST [/auth]}: There is already 'authController' bean method
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission(String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1388) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:368) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.initHandlerMappings(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.afterPropertiesSet(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'authController' method 
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission()
to {POST [/auth]}: There is already 'authController' bean method
com.sands_derek_mavdesk_casestudy.controllers.AuthController#handleFormSubmission(String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:674) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:636) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:331) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:508) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:84) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$2(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:298) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:265) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:224) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:239) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 69 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0

I have confirmed all dependencies and made sure all the code is correct to the best of my ability.  Full Disclosure this is for a bootcamp capstone project, and I present tomorrow.  I have tried all I know of

This question is similar to: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'appController' bean method. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
